# How to embed youtube channel page using iframe in my extension?

Tags: iframe, youtube, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, x-frame-options

I'm creating extension to organize youtube channels using tags. It has angular frontend with url like this

> moz-extension://f78b3bd9-a210-41c5-9d8d-9b7ab3717f6e/index.html#/channel/UCtinbF-Q-fVthA0qrFQTgXQ

And I want to embed channel's page using iframe, but security policies doesn't allow me to do that.

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.youtube.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing.

So I tried to modify X-Frame-Options, but it doesn't change anything(headers aren't added).

What I did:

1 Added permissions to manifest.json:

"webRequest",
"*://*.youtube.com/*",
"*://www.youtube.com/*"

2 Wrote some code in background.js

```
function addFramePermissions(e) {
    console.log("Loading url: " + e.url);

    var allowedHeaders = [];

    for (var header of e.responseHeaders) {
        if (header.name.toLowerCase() !== "x-frame-options") {
            allowedHeaders.push(header);
        } else {
            console.log('x-frame-options found!!!');
        }
    }

    e.responseHeaders = allowedHeaders;

    return { responseHeaders: e.responseHeaders };
}


browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    addFramePermissions,
    {
        urls: [
            "*://*.youtube.com/*",
            "*://youtube.com/*"
        ]
    },
    ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]
);
```

Code reaches function and I can see "x-frame-options found!!!" in console, but firefox's Network Monitor shows that x-frame-options exists with value SAMEORIGIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran my extension in Chrome and Chrome said that I forgot to add "webRequestBlocking" in permissions. Thanks, Chrome!